# Images not displaying in cakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0

For some reason I cannot view images in cakePHP 2.x, I have another cakePHP 1.3 running on the same machine and images are displaying perfectly for those.

I can get images by their full path.

However, I cannot access

```
http://localhost/app/webroot/img/image.png
```

If I use an image name that does not exist, then I get an error in Apache. So it does somehow see the image.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Its due .htaccess misconfiguration. Check your .htaccess in /, app/, and app/webroot .

Answer (score 0):

```
$this -> Html -> image('add_row.jpg',
                        array(
                                'escape'   => false,
                                'width'    => '20',
                                'height'   => '20',
                                'fullBase' => true,
                                'alt'      => 'No Image' 
                             )
                       )
```

Use "fullBase" attribute in the options array as it will get absolute path for the Image LINK. It might solve your problem.